# How to center my DIV, it wont go

Tags: html, css

My "#pojat"-part just wont center. I've tried " width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;" also using % wont change anything, plz helpme.

It just wont go center, it goes "mostly" center and i dont know wtf is blocking my div centering.

```css
body,
 html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#000;
  background:#a7a09a;
 }
 #wrap {
  
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#99c;
 }
 #header {
     padding:5px 10px;
  background:#ddd;
 }
 h1 {
     margin:0;
  text-align: center;
    }
 
 #pojat {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #b0e0e6;
  text-align: justify;
  
  }
 h2 { 
  margin:0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #Ilkka {
  float:left;
  display: inline;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#99c;
 }
 #Lari {
  float:left;
  display: inline;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#99c;
 }
 #Jaakko {
  float:left;
  display: inline;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#99c;
 }
 #footer {
  clear:both;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:#cc9;
 }
 #footer p {
  margin:0;
    }
 * html #footer {
  height:1px;
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  max-width: 99%:
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Responsive Design By Poikabändi</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="header"><h1>PoikaBändi</h1></div>
 <div id="pojat">
   <div id="Ilkka">
    <h2>Ilkka</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="Lari">
    <h2>Lari</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
    
   </div>
   <div id="Jaakko">
    <h2>Jaakko</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean the div pojat?

Comment: Side note: the DOCTYPE is not for HTML5...

Comment: it is centered, but with full width, make width:50% and you will see. Blocks inside floats to left inside centered div.

Comment: Yes i can see. But how i can adjust it so it works

Comment: The div is centering, but the div inside it are floating to the left. The problem is there.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `text-align: center` to parent and `display: inline-block` to child. Also you can add `text-align: justify` to each child seperate or use a class:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #a7a09a;
}
#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #99c;
}
#header {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#pojat {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#Ilkka {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99c;
  text-align: justify;
}
#Lari {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99c;
  text-align: justify;
}
#Jaakko {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99c;
  text-align: justify;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #cc9;
}
#footer p {
  margin: 0;
}
* html #footer {
  height: 1px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  max-width:99%:
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>PoikaBändi</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="pojat">
      <div id="Ilkka">
        <h2>Ilkka</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="Lari">
        <h2>Lari</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="Jaakko">
        <h2>Jaakko</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it didnt do anything what i wanted @AlexChar

Comment: You din't want to center elements in `div` with id #pojat ?

Comment: It works, and has one extra feature compared to my solution: inner `div`s wrap nicely when the window is small---better for responsive design, as the title from Ilkka suggests.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking twice about my answer, how about changing to:

```
#pojat {
  width: 669px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #b0e0e6;
  text-align: justify;
}

#Ilkka {
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#99c;
}
```

And same thing for `#Larri` and `#Jaakko`.

The differences are:

- Fixed width for the outter `div`, just large enough to enclose the internal `div`s.
- Use of `display:inline-block;` instead of just `inline`.

(my original answer was just wrong, missing half of the style sheet submitted)

Comment: didn't change anything! @EricPlaton

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with margin-left: 25%?

Answer (score 0):

body,
    html {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:#000;
        background:#a7a09a;
    }
    #wrap {

```
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#99c;
}
#header {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#ddd;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#pojat {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto 2.5%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    text-align: justify;
    border:1px solid #f00;;
    height: auto;

    }
    #pojat>div{
        width:30%;
        margin: 0 1.5%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background:#99c;
        padding:0px;
        float:left;
    }
h2 { 
    margin:0 0 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#cc9;
}
#footer p {
    margin:0;
}
* html #footer {
    height:1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    max-width: 99%:

}s
```

Answer (score 0):

Ops :) Your Code is just OK

`#pojat` is centered . The reason you feel it is not , is that you cant understand it while it has `width:95%`

Add This To CSS :

`.clearfix {clear: both;margin: 0;}`

Then Add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` befor end of div#pojat .
Now , change `#pojat` width to less value . 50% for example . check the results .

This is `width:50%;` . you can see how #pojat is center .
[image]